# Spring Boot enable <async-supported> like in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring Boot configuration. I got exception on some mobile devices which should use sockets:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.<init>(ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.java:59)
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getAsyncRequestControl(ServletServerHttpRequest.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:322)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    ...
```

As I see from the exception, I have to enable async processing by adding true into the web.xml file. But this is the problem because I don't have it - our project uses Spring Boot.

Is there any way to provide the same functionality in Spring Boot like  does?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to define `dispatcherServlet` `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServletRegistrationBean registration = new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(
            new DispatcherServlet(), "/");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
}
```

It overrides that default one from `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: If it complains about raw types, write `ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet>` instead of `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Or just `DispatcherServletRegistrationBean`. At the time I wrote this answer there was no that generic type on the `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Answer (score 4):

Even though I am late to the party I am posting my working solution for posterity.

I had faced the same issue and tried the solution suggested by @Artem Bilan. But after debugging the code, I came to know that the `servletRegistrationBean.isAsyncSupported()` is by default `true`.

[image].

The actual error is being generated by the code block is from the method `org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.startAsync()`  and we are getting this error when `getRequest().isAsyncSupported()` is `false`. Despite the `ServletRegistrationBean#asyncSupported` value is `true`, `HttpServletRequest#isAsyncSupported()` method value is always set to `false` for all API requests.

The Exerpt of the code block [Code Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/da071c1fceb48ac32ebab105d04a204d1ac8642e/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java#L112)

```
Assert.state(getRequest().isAsyncSupported(),
                "Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved " +
                "in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API " +
                "or by adding \"<async-supported>true</async-supported>\" to servlet and " +
                "filter declarations in web.xml.");
```

When analyzing further, I came to know that requestAttributes -> Globals.ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR decides whether the request has to be processed in an Async way or not.

During the normal scenario, the requests do not have `Globals.ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR` requestAttribute, hence `request.asyncSupported` will be false, if we manually add that requestAttribute `ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR` value as true for all the requests using something like filters then `request#asyncSupported` value will be set to `true` as per the below code block [Code Reference](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/61b8b76571bc10a0fd7e8199122ae96154992fad/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L3435)

```
specialAttributes.put(Globals.ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR,
                new SpecialAttributeAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public Object get(Request request, String name) {
                        return request.asyncSupported;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void set(Request request, String name, Object value) {
                        Boolean oldValue = request.asyncSupported;
                        request.asyncSupported = (Boolean)value;
                        request.notifyAttributeAssigned(name, value, oldValue);
                    }
                });
```

Though there is no explicit answer, I have implemented a workaround for this issue. To Summarize all the required changes are listed below:

1. Add a filter to set the request attribute as `request.setAttribute(Globals.ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR, true)`

```
@Component
public class AsyncSupportFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute(Globals.ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR, true);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

2. Add filter to into your filter chain, in my case I have registered my filter into the spring context as below.

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private AsyncSupportFilter asyncSupportFilter = null;
   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

       httpSecurity.addFilter(asyncSupportFilter);
       // we can add the filter before any filter like as httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(asyncSupportFilter , BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this filter and it solved my problem. Note that, I didn't add the filter into the filter chain. Spring is handling that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it worth to mention that Spring Boot has async-support enabled by default for dispatcher servlet and all filters

Quotation from [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1665):

> We automatically set async-supported to true
>   because the DispatcherServlet knows how to work with such requests and
>   it's basically up to individual controller methods to return something
>   like a DeferredResult. Furthermore, we also set async-supported for
>   any filter (provided via getServletFilters) along with setting the
>   DispatcherType for each filter to include ASYNC.

At least my practice supports this statement

Comment: Does that practice include deploying Spring app on tomcat and not standalone app?

Comment: @Antoniossss that my answer was made during a migration project of a monolith spring (not spring boot) application to a set of standalone spring boot services. Previous, monolithic, non-spring boot version of the app had to turn on async-supported explicitly as far as I remember.

Comment: This turns out not to be true.

Comment: The behavior has changed in Spring Boot? The abovementioned statement was made by Spring Boot authors in 2014.....

Comment: I say it too but too but it was just not wrorking. We had to ass something like @EnableAsync somewhere - cannot remember exactly, but it was a matter of singe annotation (that does not relates to this at first glance)

Answer (score 0):

mysolution:

```
@WebFilter(value = {"/subscriberinfo/query/single/*"})
public class ...Filter{
}
```

TO

```
@WebFilter(value = {"/subscriberinfo/query/single/*"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class ...Filter{
}
```