# How to register a servlet with enabled "async-supported" in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

I'm planing to migrate my old app to Spring-Boot.
I want to stop using web.xml descriptor and register old pure Servlet ("async-supported" enabled) and an associated ServletContextListener.

Comment: And where is the real question? What steps you made so far?

Comment: I know that both object should be annoted as bean. But I dont know what wrapping object sholud i use.

Comment: What do you mean with wrapping object? Show us some code at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot will automatically register any `Servlet` beans in your application context with the servlet container. By default async supported is set to `true` so there's nothing for you to do beyond creating a bean for your `Servlet`.

If, for whatever reason, you want to take more control over your servlet's registration, then, rather than exposing the Servlet itself as a bean, you can wrap it in a `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a @EnableAsync on your application class.
See [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`servletRegistrationBean.isAsyncSupported()` is by default `true` which decides whether the Async functionality is supported or not.

[image].

If you are facing below issue then follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213050/spring-boot-enable-async-supported-like-in-web-xml/61895963#61895963)

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a
>   servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This
>   is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding
>   "true" to servlet and filter
>   declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container