# SpringBoot: Control Async behaviour from @RequestMapping analogous to an AsyncWebServlet?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, servlets, spring-restcontroller

I am working with Spring Boot 2 and I would like my requests to be handled asynchronously.

In Java EE, one can use Asynchronous Processing for Asynchronous Servlets as in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm). The following is a related example:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/asyncservlet"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

and the above allows to use AsyncContext.

But in Spring Boot, I have the following `@RequestMapping`. How do I make it handle requests in Asynchronous mode and also supporting AsyncContext? How do I leverage the use of an Asynchronous Web Servlet?

```
@RestController
public class myRestController {
   @RequestMapping("{resource}/**")
   public void resourceRequest (@PathVariable("resource") String resource) {
       // example:
       // ... some long running calls such as database communication
       // ... convert request through  AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();
       // etc
   }
```

}

Note that returning `void` is intentional.

I found the following SO answer [How to register a servlet with enabled "async-supported" in Spring-Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720758/how-to-register-a-servlet-with-enabled-async-supported-in-spring-boot) saying that "Spring Boot will automatically register any Servlet beans in your application context with the servlet container. By default async supported is set to true so there's nothing for you to do beyond creating a bean for your Servlet." but I am not using any `@WebServlet` annotations anywhere in my program, just the `@RestController` annotation. So how do I ensure that I am benefitting from `asyncSupported` option?