# async-supported gets disabled when configuring HTTPS with Tomcat and Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm currently working on a Springboot 2.1 application with tomcat and HTTPS enabled. We are trying to write some new APIs using the new Reactive stack provided by spring-webflux. Since the application still has traditional blocking endpoints we need to use Tomcat with async-supported enabled for the new non blocking APIs to work.

When running the API and trying to hit the endpoint over HTTPS I get the following error :

```
ERROR c.b.b.c.u.s.r.c.ApiExceptionHandler - Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.
```

**If I disable HTTPS and hit the API using HTTP the request works and I get the response from the new non blocking API controller.**

Currently HTTPS is configured using the following code (if I remove this config the non blocking api works):

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    private final SslProperties sslProperties;
    private final LogbackAccessProperties logbackAccessProperties;

    public BootConfig(SslProperties sslProperties, LogbackAccessProperties logbackAccessProperties) {
        this.sslProperties = sslProperties;
        this.logbackAccessProperties = logbackAccessProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addContextValves(getLogbackValve());
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            Http11NioProtocol proto = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
            proto.setSSLEnabled(true);
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(true);
            proto.setKeystoreFile(sslProperties.getKeyStoreLocation());
            proto.setKeystorePass(sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword());
            proto.setKeystoreType(sslProperties.getKeyStoreType());
            proto.setTruststoreFile(sslProperties.getKeyStoreLocation());
            proto.setTruststorePass(sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword());
            proto.setTruststoreType(sslProperties.getKeyStoreType());
            proto.setKeyAlias(sslProperties.getHostingServerKeyAlias());
            proto.setSslEnabledProtocols("TLSv1.2");
        });
    }

    private LogbackValve getLogbackValve() {
        LogbackValve valve = new LogbackValve();
        valve.setFilename(logbackAccessProperties.getConfig());
        return valve;
    }
}
```

Reading online I can see Springboot by default enables `async-supported` when using tomcat and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` with `spring-mvc`. This seems to be the case when using HTTP but when setting HTTPS doesn't seem to work anymore. is there another way to enable it when setting up HTTPS?

Comment: did you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213050/spring-boot-enable-async-supported-like-in-web-xml ??

Comment: yes I saw that and tried it before posting the question but it didn't solve the problem. I ended finding the issue and have posted how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the cause of the problem. Using HTTPS is not causing the issue. I believed this was the case since when I removed the `public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {...` method it worked.

Look like async was being disabled by the `LogbackValve` that was being added. The valve needs to be set with `asyncSupported=true` in order to work. So I had to update my method to:

```
    private LogbackValve getLogbackValve() {
        LogbackValve valve = new LogbackValve();
        valve.setFilename(logbackAccessProperties.getConfig());
        valve.setAsyncSupported(true); // This line fixed the issue
        return valve;
    }
```

From reading the documentation this was not very obvious so took me a while to figure it out. I hope it helps if someone face the same issue :)